Local ring of nonclosed point as a ring of functions
Let $R$ be a unital commutative ring without nilpotents. Call a function $f$ from its closed points to corresponding fields, regular at $\mathfrak{m} \in \operatorname{maxspec} R$ if there is a relatively open $U\subset $ maxspec $R$ containing $\mathfrak{m}$, and $g, h \in R$, $h$ nonvanishing on $U$, such that $f = g/h$ on $U$.
Question. What is a sufficient condition on $R$, which would allow to identify the localizations at nonclosed points $\mathfrak{p}$ with the germs of regular functions on opens $U$ meeting $V(\mathfrak{p})$ $\cap$ maxspec $R$?
Hartshorne chapter I.3 exercise 13 shows that this works when $R$ is the ring of a variety over an algebraically closed field. Shouldn't all we need in general be something like $R$ Jacobson?

If you didn't add the "maxspec", you wouldn't need any conditions: if $f\in R_P$, then by definition of the localization there are $g\in R$ and $h\in R\setminus P$ such that $f=g/h$, and then one may select $U=D(h)$, which is nonempty as $h$ is not nilpotent (since it's not in the prime ideal $P$). Worrying about maxspec and closed points of the original space means that you need to ensure that $D(h)\cap V(P)$ has closed points for every non-nilpotent $h$, which is equivalent to the closed points being dense in every closed subset of $\operatorname{Spec} R$, which is in turn equivalent to $R$ Jacobson.
Definition. (Stacks 005U) Let $X$ be a topological space and let $X_0$ be the subspace of closed points of $X$. We say that $X$ is Jacobson if every closed subset $Z\subset X$ is the closure of $Z\cap X_0$.
Lemma. (Stacks 00G3) A ring $R$ is Jacobson iff $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is Jacobson as a topological space.
(Personally, I don't think it's super productive to require this for general theory, and maybe you'll come around on this as you see more schemes :)
